# execute a ruby thread in a specific context

Tags: ruby, multithreading

In the spirit of `instance_exec` with blocks, is there a way to do something similar for a thread? Instead of:

```
def context_thread_for(object, *args, &block)
  Thread.new do
    object.instance_exec(*args, &block)
  end
end

context_thread_for(custom_dsl_object) { dsl_method }
```

Is there a way to pass the context right to the thread without wrapping it?

Trying to benchmark different approaches because I read somewhere `instance_exec` is slow, but I can't figure out how to do it. Maybe with a `binding`?

**edit**

Dennis, I'd wanna use it for this: https://github.com/aj0strow/async_enum#preventing-race-conditions

Comment: `Thread#new` accepts arguments that are then passed to the thread. Might that be what you're looking for?

Comment: @Denis not a bad idea at all, but I want to provide methods in the block that are not globally defined (not on Kernel) DSL-style

Comment: Perhaps the question would be more clear if you gave more explanations and a proper example of whatever you're trying to achieve. Re-reading it and your comment makes me scratch my head even more than I initially was.